# Find the rule of $y$ : $x^2y'-y^2=\frac {x^2}{4} $

Tags: calculus

> Find  the rule  of  $y$
>
> $x^2y'-y^2=\frac {x^2}{4} $

Can i have a help in this question please

Comment: This is a [first order homogeneous differential equation](https://www.mathsisfun.com/calculus/differential-equations-homogeneous.html) since it can be written in the form $y'=F\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint...substitute $y=vx$ and then you have a separable variable differential equation

Accordingly, $y'=v'x+v$ and now form an equation with $v$ and $x$ terms only

Comment: Thank you  ,  but what is  " $vx $?

Comment: please can you elaborate A bit more please?

Comment: $v$ is another function of $x$. Once you have found this you can find $y$

Comment: may  you write the step of substitution  and i continue,  please?

Comment: Use the product rule to find $y'$.

Comment: @Medo see my edited answer

Comment: @projectilemotion  i need the step of substitution ,  can you elaborate it please?

Comment: @projectilemotion, after substituting $y'$ and $y$ you have $$x^2(v'x+v)-v^2x^2=\frac{x^2}{4}\implies v'x+v-v^2=\frac{1}{4}\implies \frac{v'}{v^2-v+0.25}=\frac{1}{x}$$ please continue.

Comment: For the LHS, complete the square on the denominator and perform a substitution. The RHS integral is easy.